# HTML Table, дорисовать колонку слева таблицы

Tags: javascript, html

Представьте лист бумаги, вы рисуете таблицу. Если нужна еще 1 колонка слева - просто берёте и дорисовываете слева. Как точно такое сделать в HTML? Добавляя колонку на позицию "0" обычным споcобом row.insertCell(0) - она встаёт на место предыдущей первой, все остальные колонки сдвигая вправо. Необходимо, чтоб колонка появилась слева и у таблицы стали новые координаты Х.

Добавить колонку обычным способом и передвинуть всю таблицу влево на ширину новой колонки не предлагать. Нужен способ технически работающий как на бумаге.

Код обычного метода, двигающий табличку вправо (надо наоборот):

```
<html>
<head>
    <script type='text/javascript'>
        function addColumnLeft() {
            var tblBodyObj = document.getElementById('tbl').tBodies[0];
            for (var i=0; i<tblBodyObj.rows.length; i++) {
                var newCell = tblBodyObj.rows[i].insertCell(0);
            }
        }
    </script>

    <style>
        table, td {
            table-layout: fixed;
            border: 1px solid black;
            width: 100px;
            height: 100px;
        }
    </style>
</head>

<body>
    <table id="tbl" style="position:absolute; top:10px; left:300px;">
    <tr>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>2</td>
        <td>3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>5</td>
        <td>6</td>
        <td>7</td>
    </tr>
    </table>

<button onclick="addColumnLeft();">add column</button>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Даже на бумаге технически это работает пока не закончится бумага :(

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Добавляешь колонку первой и вешаешь на ячейки css-класс extra-left-column и делаешь такой css:

```
table {
  position: relative;
}

.extra-left-column {
  position: absolute;
  width: 7em; /* любая нужная ширина */
  left: -7em; /* она же, но с минусом */
}
```

Ну и таблица должна заранее иметь достаточно пустого пространства слева. Это можно сделать, например, так:

```
table {
  margin-left: 7em;
}
```

А вообще, по-моему, правильно будет сразу сделать таблицу с нужными ячейками, и просто скрыть временно ненужные

Comment: Пожалуй самое правильное решение. Немного кривовато новые ячейки ставятся если все координаты\размеры имеющихся ячеек по дефолту, но это поправимо

Comment: @qwerty007, нет, у имеющихся не должны. Достаточно того, что они будут той же высоты.

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте этот, думаю Вам подходит (Версия 1)

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.3.2.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#exampleTable').find('td').each(function(i, el) {
        var inputEl = $(el).children().get(0);
        $(el).before('<td>Added ' + $(inputEl).attr('type') + '</td>');
   });


});
</script>
```

или [Версия 2](http://jsfiddle.net/8UdQ9/)

```
$("tbody tr").each( function() {
   $(this).find("td:eq(" + cellBefore + ")").after("<td>" + spliceFirst + "</td>");
   $(this).find("td:eq(" + cellAfter + ")").after("<td>" + spliceLast + "</td>");
 });
```

или по проще [Версия 3](http://jsfiddle.net/wtD7x/)

```
$("tbody tr").each( function() {
    $(this).find("td:eq(" + column + ")").after("<td>" + spliceFirst + "</td>").before("<td>" + spliceLast + "</td>");
 });
```

Comment: К сожалению нет, это работает как и row.insertCell(0), сдвигая все другие колонки вправо, координата Х таблицы не меняется. Другие колонки визуально должны остаться на прежнем месте

Comment: Передвинте тогда таблицу в лево на ширину добавленного столбца

Comment: В вопросе указано "Добавить колонку обычным способом и передвинуть всю таблицу влево на ширину новой колонки не предлагать. Нужен способ технически работающий как на бумаге" :)

Comment: Тогда покажите Ваш код. Это можно сделать над работой вышестоящего DIV. Если дали бы код, можно было бы легче ориентироватся

Comment: Saidolim, cкажите, а вам удобно производить какие-то действия, когда они висят на селекте? если да, то не подскажите как можно сразу же произвести действие, зашитое в первом пункте вашего селекта?

Comment: Добавил код обычного метода добавления колонки

Comment: Спасибо MasterAlex, этот код я дал как пример. а запускать его это дело автора вопроса.

Answer (score 1):

Сразу оговорюсь, что добавление колонки написал первым вараинтом, который пришёл в голову, но в примерах это не основная идея, поэтому при желании можно использовать любой другой вариант.

Вот первый вариант, но он скорее всего автору не подойдёт, всё-таки колонка немного двигается, но с точки зрения правильности в вебе, он будет более адаптивным:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var i = 0;
  $('button').click(function() {
    $('tr').prepend('<td>cell ' + i + '</td>');
    i = i - 1;
  });
});
```

```css
table {
  margin: 0 auto;
}
td {
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>cell 1</td>
      <td>cell 2</td>
      <td>cell 3</td>
      <td>cell 4</td>
      <td>cell 5</td>
      <td>cell 6</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>cell 1</td>
      <td>cell 2</td>
      <td>cell 3</td>
      <td>cell 4</td>
      <td>cell 5</td>
      <td>cell 6</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>

<button>Click me</button>
```

Второй же вариант, это именно то, чего желает автор, отступ для примера взял рэндомный, а окончание листа определяется, по средней ячейке в таблице и если она больше оставшегося места, то ячейка не добавляется и появляется сообщение:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var i = 0;
  $('button').click(function() {
    var tabMargin = parseFloat($('table').css('margin-left'));
    var tableCellLength = $('tr').find('td').length;
    var tableWidth = parseFloat($('table').css('width'));

    if (tabMargin - tableWidth / tableCellLength - 15 > 0) {
      $('tr').prepend('<td>cell ' + i + '</td>');
      var addCellWidth = parseFloat($('tr').find('td').eq(0).css('width'));
      $('table').css('margin-left', tabMargin - addCellWidth - 6 + 'px');
      i = i - 1;
    } else {
      alert('Вы пытаетесь нарисовать ячейку на столе');
    }
  });
});
```

```css
table {
  margin-left: 175px;
}
td {
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>cell 1</td>
      <td>cell 2</td>
      <td>cell 3</td>
      <td>cell 4</td>
      <td>cell 5</td>
      <td>cell 6</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>cell 1</td>
      <td>cell 2</td>
      <td>cell 3</td>
      <td>cell 4</td>
      <td>cell 5</td>
      <td>cell 6</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>

<button>Click me</button>
```

**UPD.** Вариант 3. Таблица больше не прыгает, но ограничение по ширине делать не стал, можно при желании взять из второго варианта:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var j = 0;
  var tableRowLength = $('#mainTable').find('tr').length;
  for (var i = 0; i < tableRowLength; i++) {
    $('#tablePaste').append('<tr></tr>');
  }
  $('button').click(function() {
    $('#tablePaste').find('tr').prepend('<td>cell ' + j + '</td>');
    j = j - 1;

  });
});
```

```css
table {
  margin-left: 200px;
}
td {
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
}
.paste-box {
  position: relative;
  width: 201px;
  text-align: right;
}
#tablePaste {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
}
#tablePaste td {
  white-space: nowrap;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="paste-box">
  <table id="tablePaste">
  </table>
</div>

<table id="mainTable">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>cell 1</td>
      <td>cell 2</td>
      <td>cell 3</td>
      <td>cell 4</td>
      <td>cell 5</td>
      <td>cell 6</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>cell 1</td>
      <td>cell 2</td>
      <td>cell 3</td>
      <td>cell 4</td>
      <td>cell 5</td>
      <td>cell 6</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>


<button>Click me</button>
```

PS. Извиняюсь за мой jQuery, при желании можно переписать на нативный JS, но мне лень. :)

Comment: визуально правильно, как и ответ предыдущего человека, но технически нет - Вы всёравно в конце вручную сдвигаете табличку влево меняя 'margin-left'. Т.е. после нажатия кнопки табличка делает быстрый скачек вперёд и обратно. Нужно без скачков

Comment: а что вы имеете ввиду под фразой "визуально" правильно, говоря про ответ предыдущего автора? Лично я там не увидел ничего такого, что решает ваше задание, более того в третьем примере, ни при каких условиях ячейка не добавляется в начало, что совершенно не решает условие задания (браузер firefox).

Comment: Добавил третий вариант, где таблица не делает скачков, но придётся делать ещё одну таблицу, потому что вариантов решения без скачков при работе с одним элементом я не знаю, возможно что их и нет

Comment: Спасибо затруды :) жаль пока плюсы не могу ставить